# plotting a svg or pdf into matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pdf, svg, plot, imshow

I have the same file saved both as .pdf and as .svg
I'd like to insert the file in a regular matplotlib plot.
How can I do that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pdfFile = open('file.pdf') 
svgFile = open('file.svg') 
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].imshow(pdfFile)
ax[1].imshoe(svgFile)
plt.show()
```

Alternately I've tried with

```
from svglib.svglib 
import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF, renderPM >>> >>> drawing = svg2rlg("file.svg") >>> renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, "file.pdf")
```

Comment: Matplotlib cannot read pdf or svg format. You can convert to png and insert as image. Or you will need to save the matplotlib plot a file and use external means to combine the two files.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Also eps as well? In general, no vector form can be read. Is it so?

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi Correct.